# What's the correct HTTP response code to return for Denial of Service (DoS) attack?

Tags: apache, rest, http, servlets, webserver

I have some logic in the web server to find out if the user is trying to do a DoS attack. But what's the correct HTTP response code to return for that? Also what's a good error message I can put in HTTP body to tell the user politely that he's got into the DoS attack path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But what's the correct HTTP response code to return for that?

[RFC 6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585) suggests [429 Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4)

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

If the attack has compromised your ability to handle legitimate requests, then to those you might respond with [503 Service Unavailable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4).

Note the change in semantics - the person sending the bad requests gets a status from the 4xx Client Error class, while those not at fault get a status from the 5xx Internal Service Error class.

> what's a good error message I can put in HTTP body to tell the user politely that he's got into the DoS attack path?

*Please* stop that?

Comment: "Please stop that" -> made my day :-D :-D

Comment: 421 sounds good to me. 451 could be.